# DevDemon Forms Add-on with Expression Engine 4

Tags: add-on, forms, devdemon, ee4, ee4-upgrade

Has anyone used the Forms add-on with `EE4`?  DevDemon lists 4 as supported but I'm running into some issues and haven't found any solutions.

I've upgraded my site from previous versions of EE so I have an existing form.  The form loads on the site.  However some fields are incorrect/missing values and when editing the form in EE I get the following error in a dialog: `Failed to load Default Forms Fields.. See`XHR`Response.`

I can make updates to the form and `save` but they aren't actually saved.

Submitting the form on the site results in the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'DevDemon\Forms\Service\PHPMailer' not found in
/var/www/vhosts/[...]/system/user/addons/forms/Service/FormEmail.php on line 590
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be a misunderstanding:

> DevDemon lists 4 as supported

Unfortunately Forms is only compatible with EE2 and EE3 at this time:

http://www.devdemon.com/expressionengine-addons/forms

> REQUIREMENTS
>
> ExpressionEngine 2.3.1+ or ExpressionEngine 3

We hope to update it for EE4 soon!

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue on EE3. For anyone else having the issue, I changed the Email Library setting in Forms from PHP Mailer to EE Internal and that bypasses the issue